# How to resolve a (kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the array '[', but had 'EOF' instead at path) error?

Tags: android, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialise a JSON response from a public bus API but I have no idea what this error is suggesting. I'm using Kotlins, Android Compose, Retrofit. I suspect the entire response might be a single object in an array. However, if that is the case, there is no "name / key" for me to latch onto when de-serializing the json object.

Thank you for any comments!!

Edit: Oh dear, my mistake I forgot to include the JSON response.

> JSON

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/$metadata#BusArrivalv2/@Element",
    "BusStopCode": "65199",
    "Services": [
        {
            "ServiceNo": "109",
            "Operator": "SBST",
            "NextBus": {
                "OriginCode": "66009",
                "DestinationCode": "99009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:08:41+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.3971796666666667",
                "Longitude": "103.89481833333333",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            },
            "NextBus2": {
                "OriginCode": "66009",
                "DestinationCode": "99009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:20:11+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.3791336666666667",
                "Longitude": "103.88451533333334",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            },
            "NextBus3": {
                "OriginCode": "66009",
                "DestinationCode": "99009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:33:39+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.3576311666666667",
                "Longitude": "103.87389733333333",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            }
        },
        {
            "ServiceNo": "110",
            "Operator": "SMRT",
            "NextBus": {
                "OriginCode": "67759",
                "DestinationCode": "67759",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:15:13+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.391956",
                "Longitude": "103.88675816666667",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            },
            "NextBus2": {
                "OriginCode": "",
                "DestinationCode": "",
                "EstimatedArrival": "",
                "Latitude": "",
                "Longitude": "",
                "VisitNumber": "",
                "Load": "",
                "Feature": "",
                "Type": ""
            },
            "NextBus3": {
                "OriginCode": "",
                "DestinationCode": "",
                "EstimatedArrival": "",
                "Latitude": "",
                "Longitude": "",
                "VisitNumber": "",
                "Load": "",
                "Feature": "",
                "Type": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "ServiceNo": "118",
            "Operator": "GAS",
            "NextBus": {
                "OriginCode": "65009",
                "DestinationCode": "97009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:15:36+08:00",
                "Latitude": "0",
                "Longitude": "0",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            },
            "NextBus2": {
                "OriginCode": "65009",
                "DestinationCode": "97009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:30:36+08:00",
                "Latitude": "0",
                "Longitude": "0",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            },
            "NextBus3": {
                "OriginCode": "65009",
                "DestinationCode": "97009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:45:36+08:00",
                "Latitude": "0",
                "Longitude": "0",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            }
        },
        {
            "ServiceNo": "168",
            "Operator": "SBST",
            "NextBus": {
                "OriginCode": "46009",
                "DestinationCode": "84009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:06:51+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.4005116666666666",
                "Longitude": "103.89314716666667",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            },
            "NextBus2": {
                "OriginCode": "46009",
                "DestinationCode": "84009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:19:20+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.4038078333333335",
                "Longitude": "103.81116233333333",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            },
            "NextBus3": {
                "OriginCode": "46009",
                "DestinationCode": "84009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:30:42+08:00",
                "Latitude": "0",
                "Longitude": "0",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            }
        },
        {
            "ServiceNo": "27",
            "Operator": "SBST",
            "NextBus": {
                "OriginCode": "64009",
                "DestinationCode": "64009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:10:34+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.3906049999999999",
                "Longitude": "103.8975745",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            },
            "NextBus2": {
                "OriginCode": "64009",
                "DestinationCode": "64009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:16:14+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.3840883333333334",
                "Longitude": "103.8931035",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            },
            "NextBus3": {
                "OriginCode": "64009",
                "DestinationCode": "64009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:23:24+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.367685",
                "Longitude": "103.89199466666666",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            }
        },
        {
            "ServiceNo": "3",
            "Operator": "GAS",
            "NextBus": {
                "OriginCode": "65009",
                "DestinationCode": "75009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:09:49+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.3943108333333334",
                "Longitude": "103.912359",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            },
            "NextBus2": {
                "OriginCode": "65009",
                "DestinationCode": "75009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:17:21+08:00",
                "Latitude": "0",
                "Longitude": "0",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            },
            "NextBus3": {
                "OriginCode": "65009",
                "DestinationCode": "75009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:22:41+08:00",
                "Latitude": "0",
                "Longitude": "0",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            }
        },
        {
            "ServiceNo": "34",
            "Operator": "GAS",
            "NextBus": {
                "OriginCode": "65009",
                "DestinationCode": "65009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:08:02+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.4030624999999999",
                "Longitude": "103.905756",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SDA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            },
            "NextBus2": {
                "OriginCode": "65009",
                "DestinationCode": "65009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:19:00+08:00",
                "Latitude": "0",
                "Longitude": "0",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            },
            "NextBus3": {
                "OriginCode": "65009",
                "DestinationCode": "65009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:34:00+08:00",
                "Latitude": "0",
                "Longitude": "0",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            }
        },
        {
            "ServiceNo": "858",
            "Operator": "TTS",
            "NextBus": {
                "OriginCode": "46009",
                "DestinationCode": "46009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:07:21+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.401444",
                "Longitude": "103.88471433333333",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            },
            "NextBus2": {
                "OriginCode": "46009",
                "DestinationCode": "46009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:15:18+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.396672",
                "Longitude": "103.843551",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "BD"
            },
            "NextBus3": {
                "OriginCode": "46009",
                "DestinationCode": "46009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:32:28+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.4304945",
                "Longitude": "103.8332425",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "SD"
            }
        },
        {
            "ServiceNo": "88",
            "Operator": "SBST",
            "NextBus": {
                "OriginCode": "52009",
                "DestinationCode": "77009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:11:26+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.3829096666666667",
                "Longitude": "103.89827683333333",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            },
            "NextBus2": {
                "OriginCode": "52009",
                "DestinationCode": "77009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:16:18+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.3768328333333333",
                "Longitude": "103.89260733333333",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            },
            "NextBus3": {
                "OriginCode": "52009",
                "DestinationCode": "77009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:17:23+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.3757058333333334",
                "Longitude": "103.889185",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            }
        },
        {
            "ServiceNo": "89",
            "Operator": "SBST",
            "NextBus": {
                "OriginCode": "64009",
                "DestinationCode": "64009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:12:25+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.3876896666666667",
                "Longitude": "103.89635566666666",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            },
            "NextBus2": {
                "OriginCode": "64009",
                "DestinationCode": "64009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:24:59+08:00",
                "Latitude": "0",
                "Longitude": "0",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            },
            "NextBus3": {
                "OriginCode": "64009",
                "DestinationCode": "64009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:34:18+08:00",
                "Latitude": "0",
                "Longitude": "0",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            }
        },
        {
            "ServiceNo": "969",
            "Operator": "TTS",
            "NextBus": {
                "OriginCode": "46009",
                "DestinationCode": "75009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:07:27+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.4008453333333333",
                "Longitude": "103.89069783333333",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            },
            "NextBus2": {
                "OriginCode": "46009",
                "DestinationCode": "75009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:20:13+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.4184465",
                "Longitude": "103.8339825",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            },
            "NextBus3": {
                "OriginCode": "46009",
                "DestinationCode": "75009",
                "EstimatedArrival": "2022-12-23T11:27:14+08:00",
                "Latitude": "1.4303995",
                "Longitude": "103.83537966666667",
                "VisitNumber": "1",
                "Load": "SEA",
                "Feature": "WAB",
                "Type": "DD"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

> This is the full error:

```
Process: com.example.busexpress, PID: 20786                                                                                        
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected start of the array '[', but had 'EOF' instead at path: $
                                                                                                    
JSON input: .....isitNumber":"1","Load":"SEA","Feature":"WAB","Type":"DD"}}]}
                                                                                                    
at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonExceptionsKt.JsonDecodingException(JsonExceptions.kt:24)
                                                                                                        
at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonExceptionsKt.JsonDecodingException(JsonExceptions.kt:32)
                                                                                                        
at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.AbstractJsonLexer.fail(AbstractJsonLexer.kt:530)
                                                                                                        
at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.AbstractJsonLexer.fail$default(AbstractJsonLexer.kt:528)
                                                                                                        
at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.AbstractJsonLexer.fail$kotlinx_serialization_json(AbstractJsonLexer.kt:224)
                                                                                                        
at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.AbstractJsonLexer.unexpectedToken(AbstractJsonLexer.kt:207)
                                                                                                        
at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StringJsonLexer.consumeNextToken(StringJsonLexer.kt:74)
                                                                                                        

at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.beginStructure(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:97)
                                                                                                        

at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.merge(CollectionSerializers.kt:29)
                                                                                                        
at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractCollectionSerializer.deserialize(CollectionSerializers.kt:43)
                                                                                                        

at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:70)
                                                                                                        
at kotlinx.serialization.json.Json.decodeFromString(Json.kt:95)
                                                                                                        
at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.Serializer$FromString.fromResponseBody(Serializer.kt:30)
                                                                                                        
at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.DeserializationStrategyConverter.convert(DeserializationStrategyConverter.kt:11)
                                                                                                        
at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.converter.kotlinx.serialization.DeserializationStrategyConverter.convert(DeserializationStrategyConverter.kt:7)
                                                                                                        

at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
                                                                                                        

at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
                                                                                                        
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:504)
                                                                                                        
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                        
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                        
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                        
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@4c47cf1, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

> This is my Data Class to hold the JSON Response.

```
package com.example.busexpress.network

import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class SingaporeBus(
    @SerialName(value = "odata.metadata")
    val metaData: String,

    @SerialName(value = "BusStopCode")
    val busStopCode: String,

    @SerialName(value = "Services")
    val services: List<SingaporeBusServices>,
)

@Serializable
data class SingaporeBusServices(
    @SerialName(value = "ServiceNo")
    val busServiceNumber: String,

    @SerialName(value = "Operator")
    val busOperator: String,

    // Bus Arrival Timings
    @SerialName(value = "NextBus")
    val nextBus1: NextBusTiming,

    @SerialName(value = "NextBus2")
    val nextBus2: NextBusTiming,

    @SerialName(value = "NextBus3")
    val nextBus3: NextBusTiming
)

@Serializable
data class NextBusTiming(
    // Date-Time expressed in the UTC standard, GMT+8 for Singapore Standard Time (SST)
    @SerialName(value = "OriginCode")
    val startingBusStop: String,

    @SerialName(value = "DestinationCode")
    val endingBusStop: String,

    @SerialName(value = "EstimatedArrival")
    val estimatedArrival: String,

    // Bus Approximate Location
    @SerialName(value = "Latitude")
    val latitude: String,

    @SerialName(value = "Longitude")
    val longitude: String,

    @SerialName(value = "VisitNumber")
    val visitNumber: String,

    // Current Bus Occupancy Levels
    @SerialName(value = "Load")
    val busOccupancyLevels: String,

    // Wheelchair Support
    @SerialName(value = "Feature")
    val wheelchairAccessible: String,

    // Bus Type
    @SerialName(value = "Type")
    val vehicleType: String,
)
```

Comment: And what json do you get in the response?

Comment: @MidasLefko my apologies, I can't fathom how I left that out. It's been edited to include the JSON response

Comment: are you sure that this is the json you are receiving (can you capture the raw response body)? From the error it seems like the json you are receiving doesnt have an array in it.

Comment: @MidasLefko Yup, I realised my error, it had nothing to do with the JSON response or the Data Classes. It was because I had set the return value of my API Service as an Array. Thank you!!